# kendo angular menu without typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-ui

How I can use the kendo menu without typescript?

html

```
<kendo-menu [items]="menuItems" [vertical]="true" style="display:inline-block;" (select)="onMenuSelected($event)"></kendo-menu>
```

TS

```
    menuItems: any[] = [
        // {
        //     text: "Rename",
        // },
        {
            text: "Delete",
        },
        {
            text: "Copy",
        },
    ];
```

I want to use only html to use of menu

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you can enter the data in the template itself, like this:

```
<kendo-menu [items]="
    [{
        text: 'Rename'
    },
    {
        text: 'Delete'
    },
    {
        text: 'Copy'
    }]">
</kendo-menu>
```

Now, while it is possible, it's not good practice. Even if the menu, in this case, is static and simple, it's better to have a `const` on the component containing the menu entries, or perhaps in a dedicated file if you have many such constants which you in several places.